# The name 'modelItem' does not exist in the current context (inside foreach loop)

Tags: database, foreach, .net-core, razor-pages, tag-helpers

I have a .NET Core 2.0 Application here and, in one of my views, I used a `foreach` loop to display all of the items in this database table. Everything was working great. Now I've added another `foreach` loop inside that one contained in a Bootstrap modal to show a list of IDs but now I'm getting an error that says

> The name 'modelItem' does not exist in the current context

I'm sure of the reason. It looks like everything is right. Can someone point out why I'm getting this error or provide an alternative way to pull the desired information from the DB to display in this modal?

**View**

```
@foreach (var Submission in Model.Submissions)
{
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        // Code that populates the project cards on the page
    </div>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="StatusCodeUpdate-@Submission.ID" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="StatusCodeUpdateLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="StatusCodeUpdateLabel">Update Status Code for @Submission.Title </h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <h6>Status Codes</h6>
            <form method="post">
                @foreach (var Code in Model.StatusCodes)
                {
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem = Code.ID) // ERROR!!!

                }
            </form>
        </div>
        ...
}
```

**Code Behind**

```
public class TeamleadModel : PageModel
{
    public IList<Submission> Submissions { get; set; }
    public IList<Status> StatusCodes { get; set; }
    private readonly SubmissionContext _submissionContext;
    private readonly StatusContext _statusContext;
    public TeamleadModel(SubmissionContext submission, StatusContext statusContext)
    {
        _submissionContext = submission;
        _statusContext = statusContext;
    }

    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        Submissions = await _submissionContext.Submissions.ToListAsync();
        StatusCodes = await _statusContext.StatusCodes.ToListAsync();
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Code.ID)`. You've got an assignment instead of lambda expression.

Comment: I hate when it's something so simple. Thank you for this.

Comment: No worries.  it happens sometimes :)